# Remove Everything from a string .. Only Leave Numbers in it

Tags: python, python-2.7

The string might be:

```
JAIDK392**8'^+%&7JDJ0204İŞÇéS29487
```

I would like to remove everything from it but only leave behind numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do this is with the regular expression library `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> yourString = "JAIDK392**8'^+%&7JDJ0204İŞÇéS29487"
>>> numberOnlyString = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', yourString)
>>> print numberOnlyString
'39287020429487'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do it without using any library. You can use the built-in function ord to get the ASCII code of a character. Then you can parse every character in your string to check if it is a number (If it is its ASCII code should be between 47 and 58.

> ```
> str = "JAIDK392**8'^+%&7JDJ0204İŞÇéS29487"
> output = []
> for char in str:
>     if 47 < ord(char) < 58:
>         output.append(char)
> result=''.join(output)
> print result
> ```

Comment: Equivalently, you can use `filter` as follows: `filter(lambda x: 47 < ord(x) < 58, your_string)`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are great, but another way to do it would be:

```
>>> import string
>>> digits_only = "".join(_ for _ in your_string if _ in string.digits)
```

Comment: or just `filter`: `filter(lambda m: m in string.digits, yourString)`